# How to automate Broadlink RM Pro to turn AC on\off according to temperature?

Tags: smart-home

I have a broadlink RM pro, which controls the AirCon, and also shows the temperature.
Is there a way I can automate it in a way to let's say - turn the AC on when temperature is 26 and turn it off when temperature hits 22?
Thanks